# How to install the newest firefox version on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, firefox

I'm running Debian 9 and instead of the heavily outdated ESR version of Firefox shipping with this distribution, I would like to always use the most recent Firefox version.

Thus, I changed my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to the following:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

This worked fine for a while. However, I'm now getting the message

```
The following packages have been kept back: firefox
```

every time I run "aptitude upgrade firefox".

Running the command "aptitude dist-upgrade" gives the following results:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dev locales 
The following packages will be upgraded:
firefox{b} 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 51.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 12.0 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
firefox : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
       Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.11.dfsg) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-5 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     firefox [59.0.2-1 (now)]                           
 2)     libc-bin [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]                  
 3)     libc-dev-bin [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]              
 4)     libc-l10n [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]                 
 5)     libc6 [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]                     
 6)     libc6-dev [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]                 
 7)     locales [2.27-3 (now, unstable)]                   
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions helping to solve this issue.

// Edit:
The output of "apt policy" is:

```
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 release a=now
 500 https://riot.im/packages/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 release o=riot.im,a=testing,n=stretch,c=main,b=amd64
 origin riot.im
 2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
 release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
 origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
 release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
 origin ftp.de.debian.org
 1000 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
 release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
 origin security.debian.org
 1000 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
 release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
 origin security.debian.org
 1000 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 release v=9.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
 origin ftp.de.debian.org
 Pinned packages:
 fontconfig-config -> 2.13.0-5 with priority 1001
 libfontconfig1 -> 2.13.0-5 with priority 1001
 libnss3 -> 2:3.37.1-1 with priority 1001
 firefox -> 60.0.1-5 with priority 1001
```

Comment: Is the issue that you want to run newer Firefox, or that your Debian system is broken?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add the output of `apt policy`?

Comment: @MichaelHomer The former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Fix the "The following packages have been kept back ..." error.

Edit your sources.list as follow:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main 


deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main 
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

Removing Sid url which break `apt.`

Create (edit the content of the existing file) a `/etc/apt/preferences` file with the following contents:

```
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=proposed-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Then run remove Firefox and reinstall its dependencies from stable:

```
apt update
apt purge --autoremove firefox
apt dist-upgrade
```

Some packages (maybe) need to be reinstalled manually through:

```
apt --reinstall install package
```

Please do not use `apt remove` or `apt purge` to remove them.

2) Installing the latest available firefox on debian:
From `apt` the firefox package is an updated package but the version is `58.x` (it is not an outdated package)

If you need to install the latest version you can use `snap` it is a safe way to install the latest firefox package.

```
apt install snapd
```

Check the available versions:

```
snap find firefox:
```

sample output:

```
firefox  60.0-2   mozilla    -      Mozilla Firefox web browser
```

Install `firefox  60.0-2`:

```
snap install firefox
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my issue. However, I had to add another "Package: *" line to your /etc/apt/preferences input. Could you please edit your answer accordingly? Another "issue" with this solution is that now all my bookmarks, settings and add-ons are gone. But that isn't too surprising given that I had to purge the firefox package first.